# How to create a circle icon button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I create something similar to a `FloatingActionButton`?

Answer (score 305):

RawMaterialButton is better suited I think.

```
RawMaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  elevation: 2.0,
  fillColor: Colors.white,
  child: Icon(
    Icons.pause,
    size: 35.0,
  ),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  shape: CircleBorder(),
)
```

Comment: Although FloatingActionButton is also an option, this is definitely the better approach.

Comment: I'm getting a large horizontal padding with this approach, and I can't remove it no matter what I try. Any ideas?

Comment: I solved this issue using the  constraints property of RawMaterialButton
constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 36.0, maxWidth: 36.0, minHeight: 36.0, maxHeight: 36.0
it's probably not the best solution, but it worked.

Comment: to remove padding around button completely also add
`materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap`

Comment: For me, to remove padding I added: `constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(width: 42, height: 42),`

Comment: Best approch to me was to combine, `materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap`, `padding: EdgeInsets.all(8)` and `constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 0)`

Comment: At the time of this writing, the Flutter documentation lists `RawMaterialButton` as obsolete. Why it's not marked with an `@Deprecated` I don't know - it might be because it's still used internally (by `FloatingActionButton`, for instance).

Answer (score 257):

#### Update (use new `ElevatedButton`)

- **`ElevatedButton` (with less customizations)**

  ```dart
  ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white),
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      shape: CircleBorder(),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue, // <-- Button color
      foregroundColor: Colors.red, // <-- Splash color
    ),
  )
  ```
- **`ElevatedButton` (with more customizations)**

  ```dart
  ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Icon(Icons.menu),
    style: ButtonStyle(
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(CircleBorder()),
      padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.all(20)),
      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue), // <-- Button color
      overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>((states) {
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) return Colors.red; // <-- Splash color
      }),
    ),
  )
  ```
- **Using `InkWell`**

  ```dart
  ClipOval(
    child: Material(
      color: Colors.blue, // Button color
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.red, // Splash color
        onTap: () {},
        child: SizedBox(width: 56, height: 56, child: Icon(Icons.menu)),
      ),
    ),
  )
  ```

---

**Output (same for the last two):**

[image]

Comment: This is the better solution since it involves using the more known ElevatedButton, and make minor customizations, thus gaining all the designed behavior from a Material button

Comment: What about using FloatingActionButton ?

Answer (score 83):

You just need to use the shape: `CircleBorder()`

```
MaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  color: Colors.blue,
  textColor: Colors.white,
  child: Icon(
    Icons.camera_alt,
    size: 24,
  ),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
  shape: CircleBorder(),
)
```

[image]

Comment: make sure to set minWidth if you're using padding.

Answer (score 31):

You can use [InkWell](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) to do that:

> A rectangular area of a Material that responds to touch.

Below example demonstrate how to use `InkWell`. **Notice:** you don't need `StatefulWidget` to do that. I used it to change the state of the count.

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SettingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingPageState createState() => new _SettingPageState();
}

class _SettingPageState extends State<SettingPage> {
  int _count = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new InkWell(// this is the one you are looking for..........
        onTap: () => setState(() => _count++),
        child: new Container(
          //width: 50.0,
          //height: 50.0,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),//I used some padding without fixed width and height
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,// You can use like this way or like the below line
            //borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          child: new Text(_count.toString(), style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 50.0)),// You can add a Icon instead of text also, like below.
          //child: new Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, size: 50.0, color: Colors.black38)),
        ),//............
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to get benefit of `splashColor`, `highlightColor`, wrap `InkWell` widget using a `Material` widget with material type circle. And then remove `decoration` in `Container` widget.

Outcome:

[image]

Comment: Blassanka, thanks for the information. I ended up using the FloatingActionButton instead. But your solution will come in handy for other scenarios in the future.

Comment: This code does not create a "circle" button (anymore).

Answer (score 29):

If you need a background image, you can use CircleAvatar with IconButton. Set the backgroundImage property.

```
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(userAvatarUrl),
)
```

Example with button:

```
        CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          radius: 20,
          child: IconButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but it's not an ideal solution. The Flutter docs say that `CircleAvatar` is supposed to be used to represent a user's avatar - it's not a general-purpose button.

Answer (score 18):

You can easily do the following:

```
FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {

       },
      child: new Icon(
        Icons.arrow_forward,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 20.0,
      ),
      shape: new CircleBorder(),
      color: Colors.black12,
    )
```

The result is[image]

Comment: fyi, FlatButton is deprecated

Answer (score 12):

RaisedButton is depricated,
now you can create this by ElevatedButton.

```
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        primary: Colors.blue,
        onPrimary: Colors.black,
      ),
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

```
RawMaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  constraints: BoxConstraints(),
  elevation: 2.0,
  fillColor: Colors.white,
  child: Icon(
    Icons.pause,
    size: 35.0,
  ),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  shape: CircleBorder(),
)
```

note down `constraints: BoxConstraints()`,  it's for not allowing padding in left.

Happy fluttering!!

Answer (score 8):

There actually is an example how to create a circle IconButton similar to the FloatingActionButton.

```
Ink(
    decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
        color: Colors.lightBlue,
        shape: CircleBorder(),
    ),
    child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        onPressed: () {},
    ),
)
```

To create a local project with this code sample, run:

```
flutter create --sample=material.IconButton.2 mysample
```

Answer (score 8):

Using ElevatedButton:

```
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 60.0,
            ),
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                shape: CircleBorder(), primary: Colors.green),
          )
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

## 2021

If you need it flat (no elevation) as FlatButton is now deprecated.

```dart
TextButton(
      onPressed: (){},
      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black26),
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(const CircleBorder())),
    );
```

Answer (score 6):

I created a version with correct clipping, elevation and border. Feel free to customize it.

```
Material(
    elevation: 2.0,
    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
    color: Colors.white,
    child: InkWell(
        onTap: () => null,
        child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 1.4)),
           child: Icon(
                Icons.menu,
                size: 22,
                color: Colors.red,
            ),
        ),
    ),
)),
```

Comment: This part was what I was missing -> clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge
I guess with this approach any type of button can be created, for example a FAB with onLongPressed.
Good job.

Answer (score 4):

This code will help you to add button without any unwanted padding,

```
RawMaterialButton(
      elevation: 0.0,
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: (){},
      constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(
        width: 56.0,
        height: 56.0,
      ),
      shape: CircleBorder(),
      fillColor: Color(0xFF4C4F5E),
    ),
```

Answer (score 4):

I used this one because I like the customisation of the border-radius and size.

```
  Material( // pause button (round)
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50), // change radius size
    color: Colors.blue, //button colour
    child: InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.blue[900], // inkwell onPress colour
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 35,height: 35, //customisable size of 'button'
        child: Icon(Icons.pause,color: Colors.white,size: 16,),
      ),
      onTap: () {}, // or use onPressed: () {}
    ),
  ),

  Material( // eye button (customised radius)
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50.0),),
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.blue[900], // inkwell onPress colour
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 40, height: 40, //customisable size of 'button'
        child: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye,color: Colors.white,size: 16,),),
      onTap: () {}, // or use onPressed: () {}
    ),
  ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to create the circle icon button in Flutter. Each of the examples below will use a different method.

1. Using ElevatedButton + Icon (recommended)
2. Using MaterialButton
3. ClipOval + Material + InkWell + Padding + Icon
4. IconButton + CircleAvatar
5. Ink + IconButton

**Using ElevatedButton + Icon**

```
ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          shape: const CircleBorder(), 
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30)
      ),
      child: const Icon(
        Icons.add,
        size: 50,
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
```

),

**Output:**
[image]

**Using MaterialButton**

```
MaterialButton(
    shape: const CircleBorder(),
    color: Colors.red,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
    onPressed: () {},
    child: const Icon(
      Icons.star,
      size: 50,
      color: Colors.yellow,
    ),
```

)

**Output:**
[image]

**ClipOval + Material + InkWell + Padding + Icon**

```
ClipOval(
    child: Material(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.plus_one,
            size: 50,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

)

**Output:**
[image]

**IconButton + CircleAvatar**

```
CircleAvatar(
      radius: 50,
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      child: IconButton(
          color: Colors.black,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          iconSize: 50,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.shop),
          onPressed: () {
          // do something
          }),
```

),

**Output:**
[image]

**Ink + IconButton**

```
Ink(
    decoration:
        const ShapeDecoration(
            shape: CircleBorder(), 
            color: Colors.purple
        ),
    child: IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      iconSize: 30,
      color: Colors.white,
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
```

)

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

My contribution:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

///
/// Create a circle button with an icon.
///
/// The [icon] argument must not be null.
///
class CircleButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const CircleButton({
    Key key,
    @required this.icon,
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    this.color,
    this.onPressed,
    this.splashColor,
  })  : assert(icon != null),
        super(key: key);

  /// The [Icon] contained ny the circle button.
  final Icon icon;

  /// Empty space to inscribe inside the circle button. The [icon] is
  /// placed inside this padding.
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;

  /// The color to fill in the background of the circle button.
  ///
  /// The [color] is drawn under the [icon].
  final Color color;

  /// The callback that is called when the button is tapped or otherwise activated.
  ///
  /// If this callback is null, then the button will be disabled.
  final void Function() onPressed;

  /// The splash color of the button's [InkWell].
  ///
  /// The ink splash indicates that the button has been touched. It
  /// appears on top of the button's child and spreads in an expanding
  /// circle beginning where the touch occurred.
  ///
  /// The default splash color is the current theme's splash color,
  /// [ThemeData.splashColor].
  final Color splashColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);

    return ClipOval(
      child: Material(
        type: MaterialType.button,
        color: color ?? theme.buttonColor,
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: splashColor ?? theme.splashColor,
          child: Padding(
            padding: padding,
            child: icon,
          ),
          onTap: onPressed,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not Material solution:

```
final double floatingButtonSize = 60;
final IconData floatingButtonIcon;

TouchableOpacity(
  onTap: () {
     /// Do something...
  },
  activeOpacity: 0.7,
  child: Container(
    height: floatingButtonSize,
    width: floatingButtonSize,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(floatingButtonSize / 2),
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          blurRadius: 25,
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
          offset: Offset(0, 10),
        )
      ],
    ),
    child: Icon(
      floatingButtonIcon ?? Icons.add,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
)
```

You can use GestureDetector instead of TouchableOpacity library.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the circle shape

```
MaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {
print("Circle button pressed");
  },
  color: Colors.blue,
  textColor: Colors.white,
  child: Icon(
    Icons.favorite,
    size: 20,
  ),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
//use this class Circleborder() for circle shape.
  shape: const CircleBorder(),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a RaisedButton with an image inside (for example for social login) like this (sizedbox with fittebox is needed to contraint the image on the specified size):

```
FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
    child: SizedBox(
        height: 60,
        width: 60,
        child: RaisedButton(
             child: Image.asset(
                 'assets/images/google_logo.png'),
                 shape: StadiumBorder(),
                 color: Colors.white,
                     onPressed: () {},
                 ),
             ),
         ),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClipOval(
      child: MaterialButton( 
      color: Colors.purple,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
      onPressed: () {},
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
            child: Text(
                      '1',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will create a Circle of radius 25 and will have white color add icon in it. and If user also want to have click method that can be simply achieved by wrapping a Container widget into GestureDetector() or InkWell().

```
Container(
height: 50,
width: 50,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: Colors.blue,
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50 / 2),
),
child: Center(
child: Icon(
Icons.add,
color: Colors.white,
),
),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

## Material 3 / Flutter 3.7.0-

Here is a `CircleIconButton` widget supporting standard, filled, filled tonal and outlined types from Material 3, as described in https://m3.material.io/components/icon-buttons/overview. The widget supports also toggle feature and enabled/disabled states.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum CircleIconButtonStyle {
  standard,
  filled,
  filledTonal,
  outlined,
}

class CircleIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const CircleIconButton({
    super.key,
    required this.icon,
    this.circleIconButtonStyle = CircleIconButtonStyle.filled,
    required this.onPressed,
    this.isSelected,
    this.selectedIcon,
  });

  final IconData icon;
  final CircleIconButtonStyle circleIconButtonStyle;
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;

  /// For toggle buttons
  final bool? isSelected;
  final Widget? selectedIcon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ColorScheme colors = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      icon: Icon(icon),
      isSelected: isSelected,
      selectedIcon: selectedIcon,
      style: _CircleIconButtonStyleProvider.getStyle(
          circleIconButtonStyle: circleIconButtonStyle,
          isEnabled: onPressed != null,
          isSelected: isSelected == true,
          colors: colors),
    );
  }
}

// adapted from samples at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html
class _CircleIconButtonStyleProvider {
  static ButtonStyle? getStyle({
    required CircleIconButtonStyle circleIconButtonStyle,
    required bool isEnabled,
    required bool isSelected,
    required ColorScheme colors,
  }) {
    switch (circleIconButtonStyle) {
      case CircleIconButtonStyle.standard:
        return null;
      case CircleIconButtonStyle.filled:
        return isEnabled
            ? _enabledFilledButtonStyle(isSelected, colors)
            : _disabledFilledButtonStyle(isSelected, colors);
      case CircleIconButtonStyle.filledTonal:
        return isEnabled
            ? _enabledFilledTonalButtonStyle(isSelected, colors)
            : _disabledFilledTonalButtonStyle(isSelected, colors);
      case CircleIconButtonStyle.outlined:
        return isEnabled
            ? _enabledOutlinedButtonStyle(isSelected, colors)
            : _disabledOutlinedButtonStyle(isSelected, colors);
    }
  }

  static ButtonStyle _enabledFilledButtonStyle(
    bool selected,
    ColorScheme colors,
  ) {
    return IconButton.styleFrom(
      foregroundColor: selected ? colors.onPrimary : colors.primary,
      backgroundColor: selected ? colors.primary : colors.surfaceVariant,
      disabledForegroundColor: colors.onSurface.withOpacity(0.38),
      disabledBackgroundColor: colors.onSurface.withOpacity(0.12),
      hoverColor: selected
          ? colors.onPrimary.withOpacity(0.08)
          : colors.primary.withOpacity(0.08),
      focusColor: selected
          ? colors.onPrimary.withOpacity(0.12)
          : colors.primary.withOpacity(0.12),
      highlightColor: selected
          ? colors.onPrimary.withOpacity(0.12)
          : colors.primary.withOpacity(0.12),
    );
  }

  static ButtonStyle _disabledFilledButtonStyle(
    bool selected,
    ColorScheme colors,
  ) {
    return IconButton.styleFrom(
      disabledForegroundColor: colors.onSurface.withOpacity(0.38),
      disabledBackgroundColor: colors.onSurface.withOpacity(0.12),
    );
  }

  static ButtonStyle _enabledFilledTonalButtonStyle(
    bool selected,
    ColorScheme colors,
  ) {
    return IconButton.styleFrom(
      foregroundColor:
          selected ? colors.onSecondaryContainer : colors.onSurfaceVariant,
      backgroundColor:
          selected ? colors.secondaryContainer : colors.surfaceVariant,
      hoverColor: selected
          ? colors.onSecondaryContainer.withOpacity(0.08)
          : colors.onSurfaceVariant.withOpacity(0.08),
      focusColor: selected
          ? colors.onSecondaryContainer.withOpacity(0.12)
          : colors.onSurfaceVariant.withOpacity(0.12),
      highlightColor: selected
          ? colors.onSecondaryContainer.withOpacity(0.12)
          : colors.onSurfaceVariant.withOpacity(0.12),
    );
  }

  static ButtonStyle _disabledFilledTonalButtonStyle(
    bool selected,
    ColorScheme colors,
  ) {
    return IconButton.styleFrom(
      disabledForegroundColor: colors.onSurface.withOpacity(0.38),
      disabledBackgroundColor: colors.onSurface.withOpacity(0.12),
    );
  }

  static ButtonStyle _enabledOutlinedButtonStyle(
    bool selected,
    ColorScheme colors,
  ) {
    return IconButton.styleFrom(
      backgroundColor: selected ? colors.inverseSurface : null,
      hoverColor: selected
          ? colors.onInverseSurface.withOpacity(0.08)
          : colors.onSurfaceVariant.withOpacity(0.08),
      focusColor: selected
          ? colors.onInverseSurface.withOpacity(0.12)
          : colors.onSurfaceVariant.withOpacity(0.12),
      highlightColor: selected
          ? colors.onInverseSurface.withOpacity(0.12)
          : colors.onSurface.withOpacity(0.12),
      side: BorderSide(color: colors.outline),
    ).copyWith(
      foregroundColor:
          MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
          return colors.onInverseSurface;
        }
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
          return colors.onSurface;
        }
        return null;
      }),
    );
  }

  static ButtonStyle _disabledOutlinedButtonStyle(
    bool selected,
    ColorScheme colors,
  ) {
    return IconButton.styleFrom(
      disabledForegroundColor: colors.onSurface.withOpacity(0.38),
      disabledBackgroundColor:
          selected ? colors.onSurface.withOpacity(0.12) : null,
      side:
          selected ? null : BorderSide(color: colors.outline.withOpacity(0.12)),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using `IconButton`** :

```
IconButton(
   onPressed: () {},
   icon: const Icon(Icons.apple, size: 26, color: Colors.white),
   style: IconButton.styleFrom(
       shape: const CircleBorder(), backgroundColor: Colors.black87),
),
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try out this Card

```
Card(
    elevation: 10,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0), // half of height and width of Image
      ),
    child: Image.asset(
      "assets/images/home.png",
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Card(
        elevation: 4.0,
        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(150),
        ),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: (){},
          child: Container(
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle, color: backGroundColor),
              child: Image.asset(imageUrl)),
        )),
```

Answer (score -1):

Flutter has an `IconBox` which can be used to place a circle around an `Icon`. For a `GestureTapCallback` to be added, The `IconBox` has an `onTap`.

```
IconBox(
    onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
    bgColor: AppColor.translucent,
    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded),
  )
```

Or optionally use an `IconButton`.

```
IconButton(
  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
  icon: const IconBox(bgColor: AppColor.translucent,
    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score -2):

```dart
Container(
  width: 70.w,
  height: 70.h,
  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
  child: MaterialButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    color: Color(0xff022C43),
    textColor: Colors.white,
    child: Icon(
      Icons.arrow_forward,
      size: 24,
    ),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
    shape: CircleBorder(),
  )
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: please remove .h and .w ,  this  is for used third-party package . please edit your answer .