# How to set background color for an icon button?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, iconbutton

I want to apply background color for icon button but I don't see an explicit `backgroundColor` property for it. I want to achieve this:

[image]

Currently I was able to achieve till here:

[image]

Below is the code so far:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF13212C),
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Demo'),
    ),
    drawer: appDrawer(),
    body: new Center(
    child: new Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
 //     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: <Widget>[
      new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
       //   new Flexible(
    new TextField(
        style: new TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 16.0),
      cursorColor: Colors.green,
      decoration: new InputDecoration(

        suffixIcon: new IconButton(
            icon: new Image.asset('assets/search_icon_ivory.png'),onPressed: null),

      fillColor: Colors.black,
        contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 20.0, 10.0, 20.0),
        filled: true,
        hintText: 'What Do You Need Help With?',
        hintStyle: new TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white
        )
    )
    )
      //    )
    ]
),
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

you can wrap your IconButton with Container and use color property to achieve desire output. 
May Following Example help You.

```
 suffixIcon: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: new IconButton(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.white,),onPressed: null),
            ),
```

Comment: with this implementation you'll have a little bit weird animation when `onPressed` will be not `null`. but still will work.

Comment: Flutter has a lot of icons, always try to find the icon you want before to use an external one

Comment: You also don't get all the awesome built-in flutter ink / splash effects when using a plain container. Check out [the flutter docs for IconButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html), it has been updated to include an example of how to set background color while retaining these nice details by using an `Ink` widget

Comment: James Allen's comment is the best answer!

Answer (score 84):

You can use a Circular Avatar with the radius = text field's height/2 or whatever height you prefer.

*To figure out text field specs you can visit [material.io](https://material.io/components/text-fields/#specs)*

So the chunk of code is going to be like the following:

```
CircleAvatar(
                radius: 30,
                backgroundColor: Color(0xff94d500),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    ...
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

This way you get an Icon button with background color.
I hope this can help you guys.

[image: Icon button with background]

Answer (score 32):

From the official [Flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html#adding-a-filled-background):

> #### Adding a filled background
>
> Icon buttons don't support specifying a
> background color or other background decoration because typically the
> icon is just displayed on top of the parent widget's background. Icon
> buttons that appear in [`AppBar.actions`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/actions.html) are an example of this.
>
> It's easy enough to create an icon button with a filled background
> using the [`Ink`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Ink-class.html) widget. The `Ink` widget renders a decoration on the
> underlying [Material](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material-class.html) along with the splash and highlight [`InkResponse`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkResponse-class.html)
> contributed by descendant widgets.

Tl;dr: `IconButton` doesn't support background color out-of-the-box. Use this workaround to add the background color and the splash effect when clicking the button:

```dart
Ink(
  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
    color: Colors.blue,
    shape: CircleBorder(),
  ),
  child: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
    color: Colors.white,
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
),
```

#### [Live Demo](https://dartpad.dev/6182feb015bbb179e08bf5eb61cbabac?null_safety=true)

This is now the officially recommended way to set background color on an IconButton, and the [flutter docs have been updated to reflect this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html).

Comment: This is now the officially recommended way to set background color on an IconButton, and the [flutter docs have been updated to reflect this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html). This should be the top answer.

Comment: This works for blue - but if I change the colour to white, which is what I need, then it instead does nothing.

Comment: when i use this solution inside stack the backgroundColor doesn't show up, what is the problem here, do you think?

Comment: @DuckProgrammer Same here. Did you find a solution? I have to use CircleAvatar at this stage.

Comment: @DuckProgrammer Wrap it with `Material` widget and give the color transparent with `Colors.transparent`

Answer (score 29):

You can achieve it with `TextButton`

```
    TextButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: colorScheme.primary,
        shape: CircleBorder(),
      ),
      child: Icon(
        MdiIcons.send,
        color: colorScheme.onPrimary,
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
```

The output will look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 24):

With latest flutter and material-3 design system, this is just a piece a cake.

```
IconButton(
  onPressed: () { ... },
  icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
  style: IconButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent),
),
```

Comment: I tried this but this had no effect.

Comment: also set `useMaterial3: true,` in `theme` of `MaterialApp`

Answer (score 11):

Hope, this will satisfied you

```
Ink(
  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
     color: Colors.red,
     shape: CircleBorder(),
  ),
  child: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.delivery_dining),
    onPressed: () {
    print('pressed');
    },
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Material 3, Flutter has introduced `IconButton.filled()` constructor which gives it a background color automatically based on the material `colorScheme`. It also has the added benefit of adjusting to different icon sizes.

Example:

```dart
IconButton.filled(
    icon: const Icon(Icons.phone)
)
```

[image: dark mode filled IconButton]
[image: light mode filled IconButton]
Dark mode and light mode filled IconButtons

If you want to specify a color, use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73593292/)

Answer (score 7):

You can not do that with `IconButton` widget [yet](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18220). Good news is that you may replace it with `FlatButton` like that:

```
suffixIcon: new FlatButton(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      disabledColor: Colors.green[100],
                      child: Icon(Icons.search)),
```

`color` will be used in case `onPressed` handler is defined, otherwise it will be rendered with `disabledColor` background.

Answer (score 3):

`IconButton` does not support that, and `RaisedButton` recently is deprecated in favour of `ElevatedButton`, which supports changing background colours as well as shapes, but you cannot easily make it a perfect circle.

So to think out of the box, why not use a `FloatingActionButton`? They are just widgets too, so they can appear anywhere on the screen. For example, I'm using a FAB in a video chat demo app to toggle cameras.

[image: Use a FAB at a random location on the screen]

Example code:

```
FloatingActionButton(
  child: Icon(
    Icons.flip_camera_ios_outlined,
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
  onPressed: () {
    // do your thing here
  },
)
```

And if you aren't happy about its default size, you can always wrap it with a `SizedBox` to change the width however you see fit.

Comment: Keep in mind that FloatingActionButtons inherently have Hero-Animations that can have undesired effects when navigating.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Material

```
Material(
color:Colors.green
child:IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
    color: Colors.white,
    onPressed: () {},
  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used multiple colors to demonstrate You can do as you want. And I say that You put your IconButton into Material widget. This will also solve your Splash Color (which is slightly grey color with some transparency).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Official solution:**

Depends on [official documentation of flutter about IconButton Class](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/icon_button.dart):

> **Adding a filled background**
>
> Icon buttons don't support specifying a background color or other
> background decoration because typically the icon is just displayed on
> top of the parent widget's background. Icon buttons that appear in
> [AppBar.actions] are an example of this.
>
> It's easy enough to create an icon button with a filled background
> using the [Ink] widget. The [Ink] widget renders a decoration on the
> underlying [Material] along with the splash and highlight
> [InkResponse] contributed by descendant widgets.

So the code will be like this:

```
   Material(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    child: Ink(
      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: CircleBorder(),
      ),
      child: IconButton(
        tooltip: "Some Text...",
        icon: Icon(Icons.flash_off),
        color: Colors.black,
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ),
  );
```

See official example code from flutter, [click here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html#material.IconButton.2) ...

> Note: Reason to wrap it with `Material` widget because `Ink` is drawn
> on the underlying `Material` widget, if you remove it decoration will not appear.

Answer (score 1):

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 38,
  width: 38,
  child: ElevatedButton(
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.grey,
    onPrimary: Colors.red,
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    shape: const CircleBorder(),
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with a GestureDetector and a container. I like using this solution because of the variety of controls it gives you from the combination.

Additionally, GestureDetector opens up more interaction events if you want to incorporate those across devices.

```
GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: ClipOval(
        child: Container(
          //add extra margin to visual center icon if icon isn't balanced
          color: backgroundColor,
          width: size,
          height: size,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.question_mark_sharp,
            size: size * 0.6, //size to your preference
            color: iconColor,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Alternatively you can do this from another question [circle icon button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809351/how-to-create-a-circle-icon-button-in-flutter)

```
RawMaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  elevation: 2.0,
  fillColor: Colors.white,
  child: Icon(
    Icons.pause,
    size: 35.0,
  ),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  shape: CircleBorder(),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
suffixIcon: Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  color: Colors.blue, 
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8), 
),
child: IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
  onPressed: () {
  },
  color: Colors.white, 
),
```

),

Answer (score 0):

If you want it raised, you can use RaisedButton like this:

```dart
                          ConstrainedBox(
                            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 50),
                            child: RaisedButton(
                              color: kColorLightGrey,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 12,
                              ),
                              shape: StadiumBorder(),
                              child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                              onPressed: () {
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FloatingActionButton for such case But you cannot use FAB in a widget for multi use, it shows error. In such case use this code. It will work on images also.

```
  Card(
    color: Colors.blue,
    shape: CircleBorder(), 
    child: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.edit,
          size: 20,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          print('tapped');  
        },
      ));
```

Answer (score 0):

SizedBox(

```
            height: 45,
            child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffixIcon: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            print('Media button pressed');
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          child: Container(
                            width: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                            ),
                            child: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                print('Searching');
                              },
                              icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white,),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                    label: Text('Search here...'),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      )[enter image description here][1]
                    ),
                ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Container(
  width: 40,
  height: 40,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Theme.of(context)
        .primaryColor
        .withAlpha(200), // Background color
    shape: BoxShape.circle, // Shape of the container (optional)
  ),
  child: Center(
    child: IconButton(
        color: Colors.white,
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.call,
          size: 20,
        )),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

ElevatedButton with Theme.

```
 ElevatedButton(
  style: ButtonThemes.iconButton,
  child: Icon(
    icon,
    color: color,
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
)
```

```
static ButtonStyle get iconButton=> ButtonStyle(
  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
    backgroundColor,
  ),
  ...
);
```