# How can I add 2 tone icons without using any plugin?

Tags: flutter, icons, material-design

I don't want to add any plugins just for one icon in my app but I need two tone because the background color will vary and I don't know when it will be dark and when it will be light.

I mean icons like these - https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=twotone where icons have border of different color.

Comment: not able to understand your question, are you want to add tone icon in app?

Comment: I think I wasn't clear, I have edited my question. Hope it is clear now :)

Comment: try to stack two icons with the one below (the one that acts as edge) a little bigger than the top.

Comment: It's still under development, you can check the progress of the issue here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18384

Comment: How about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60580826/638153) by @FJCG which suggests using a `CircleAvatar`.

Answer (score 3):

If i understood your Question Correctly,  here is an example of two Color Tone `Icon` & `Text`.

You can play around with Color, radius & other Parameters to fit your Needs.

```
body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ShaderMask(
              blendMode: BlendMode.srcATop,
              shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
                return RadialGradient(
                  center: Alignment.topLeft,
                  radius: 1.0,
                  colors: <Color>[Colors.red, Colors.cyanAccent],
                  tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
                ).createShader(bounds);
              },
              child: Text(
                'Two Tone Color Icon & Text!',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            ShaderMask(
              blendMode: BlendMode.srcATop,
              shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
                return RadialGradient(
                  center: Alignment.center,
                  radius: 1.0,
                  colors: <Color>[
                    Colors.greenAccent[200],
                    Colors.blueAccent[200]
                  ],
                  tileMode: TileMode.repeated,
                ).createShader(bounds);
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.dashboard,
                size: 32.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hey, I didn't know this was possible. Thanks for replying but what I needed was a simple border to my icons. I think I wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: @KeertiPurswani - I guess that wont be possible as such - without using external plugin.