# Fill background color of Image in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

Is it possible to add a background color to the Icon image? I am using the below code to render icon.

```
      Icon(
            Icons.check_circle_outline,
            size: 35.0,
          )
```

I want output like below when the image is drawn

[image]

Comment: does this answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52777666/7924072

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya: That will not help in icons case, do you have any other solution?

Comment: you can wrap it inside a container and change the background color by giving the container a color also you can change the icon color, other than that you can't do any change to icon, you should get an icon and put it in your assets and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Solution provide an exact output

```
Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: ClipOval(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.check,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 30,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you try to get the icon exactly like in your picture then this is not possible. The icon `check_circle_outline` looks like the following:

[image]

So you have a checkmark and a circle all in one icon. What you want is to change only parts of the icon (in your case the circle)

But if you just want to add a background color behind the icon, then you can do it like Viren said:

```dart
Container(
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: Icon(
    Icons.check_circle_outline,
    size: 35.0,
  ),
)
```

[image]

If you want the exact same icon as in your picture, use another icon `check` circle and this snippet:

```dart
ClipOval(
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.green,
    child: Icon(        
      Icons.check,
      color: Colors.white,
      size: 35.0,
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an exact UI?  This will not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Container(
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: Icon(
    Icons.check_circle_outline,
    size: 35.0,
  ),
),
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an exact UI?  This will not work for me.

Comment: This is the only code I am having inside my container.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the shape and size of your icon, stacking your icon on top of a square widget that has your desired background color can work.

```
  Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
    Container(height: 20.0, width: 20.0, color: Colors.black),
    Icon(Icons.photo_size_select_actual, color: Colors.cyanAccent, size: 35.0)
  ]),
```

You could stack on top of a circular widget as well.