# How to create circular button with border in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I found [How to create a circle icon button in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809351/how-to-create-a-circle-icon-button-in-flutter?rq=1) which has this code:

```
RawMaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  elevation: 2.0,
  fillColor: Colors.white,
  child: Icon(
    Icons.pause,
    size: 35.0,
  ),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  shape: CircleBorder(),
)
```

which works fine, but I can't insert a border with color. Looking on https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/CircleBorder-class.html I cannot find any ways to insert a border.

What's the simplest way to insert a border in a circular button in Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the border by applying the side property to the CircleBorder. See the code below.

```
     RawMaterialButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      elevation: 2.0,
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      child: Icon(
        Icons.pause,
        size: 35.0,
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      shape: CircleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(width: 5, color: Colors.red, style: BorderStyle.solid),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can set the border for the button:

```dart
shape: CircleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(width: 5.0, style: BorderStyle.solid, color: Colors.red)
      ),
```

[image]